# How to modify type in a table of SQLite in Android, using onUpgrade method?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, upgrade

Following this good example http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/notepad/NotePad/src/org/openintents/notepad/NotePadProvider.java?r=3878

I implement my sqlite database upgrade system. But in the link above the only example show how add new column in a table. The piece of code in the onUpgrade method is

```
 try {
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " +   NOTES_TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN "
                                                                    + Notes.TAGS + " TEXT;");
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + NOTES_TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN "
                                                                    + Notes.ENCRYPTED + " INTEGER;");
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + NOTES_TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN "
                                                                    + Notes.THEME + " TEXT;");
      } catch (SQLException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error executing SQL: ", e);
      // If the error is "duplicate column name" then everything is fine,
      // as this happens after upgrading 2->3, then downgrading 3->2, 
      // and then upgrading again 2->3.
      }
      //  *** other upgrade from version x->y
      // ***
```

and in onCreate, something like this:

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + NOTES_TABLE_NAME + " ("
           // Version 2:
           + Notes._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
           + Notes.TITLE + " TEXT,"
           + Notes.NOTE + " TEXT,"
           + Notes.CREATED_DATE + " INTEGER,"
           + Notes.MODIFIED_DATE + " INTEGER,"
           // Version 3:
           + Notes.TAGS + " TEXT,"
           + Notes.ENCRYPTED + " INTEGER,"
           + Notes.THEME + " TEXT,"
           // Version 4:
           + Notes.SELECTION_START + " INTEGER,"
           + Notes.SELECTION_END + " INTEGER,"
           + Notes.SCROLL_POSITION + " REAL"
           + ");");
          }
```

Now I want a new database version where no column is added, but I want just change type of some field in a table. How can I do this?

Here http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html is said that is not possible to change a field type. How can I circumvent the problem?

I'm inserting data in database in this way:

```
   ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
   v.put("field1", myString); // fileld1 in db is defined as integer

   dbManager.updateTable("mytable", v, whereClause);
```

How can I make a CAST in this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQLite indeed does not allow changing existing table columns.

However, [SQLite uses dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so what column type you set in the table definition does not really matter (except for conversions due to [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity)).

In the general case, any changes to tables (other than new columns) require that you create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable (...);
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM MyTable;
DROP TABLE MyTable;
ALTER TABLE TempTable RENAME TO MyTable;
```

If you want to change the type of values already stored in the table, you have to use `CAST`:

```
...
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT CAST(col1 AS TEXT), ... From MyTable;
...
```

For new values, just put a value with the correct type into the `ContentValues` object.

Comment: I'm using ContentValues for insert String data in Integer field of database. (I edited my answer). How can I make a CAST in this situation?